# rsync creates an empty directory on some hosts

Tags: rsync

I am running a backup script as a cron-job that looks (roughly) like this:

```
# Generate temporary directory for output
dest_file=backup-$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M") # e.g. backup-20200417-0400
abs_dest_file=/backup/${dest_file}      # e.g. /backup/backup-20200417-0400
mkdir -p ${abs_dest_file}

# Copy some stuff to the folder
...

# Generate a tarball
# (creates e.g. /backup/backup-20200417-0400.tar.gz)
tar -C $(dirname ${abs_dest_file}) -czvf ${abs_dest_file}.tar.gz ${dest_file}

# Clean up
rm -r ${abs_dest_file} # /backup/backup-20200417-0400 should be gone here !!

# Sync with some remote hosts
/usr/bin/rsync -avz --include "*.tar.gz" --exclude "*" $(dirname ${abs_dest_file})/ user@host1:/backup
/usr/bin/rsync -avz --include "*.tar.gz" --exclude "*" $(dirname ${abs_dest_file})/ user@host2:/backup
```

On `host1` it works as expected: I end up with a file `/backup/backup-20200417-0400.tar.gz`.

On `host2` however there is also an *empty* directory created, e.g. I end up with

```
/backup/backup-20200417-0400           # <- empty folder
/backup/backup-20200417-0400.tar.gz
```

I don't understand why this happens, and I think this is strange for two reasons:

1. The folder is removed from the machine before calling `rsync`
2. I explicitly only include tarballs when calling `rsync`

Edit: I should also note that this only happens when the script is run by cron. Just executing the script from the shell does not result in the empty folder.
Edit 2: Annoyingly it does not happen if I just schedule a cronjob for debugging -- it only shows up during the nightly cron job (but then it happens consistently)...

---

`rsync` versions: `host`, `host2`: `3.1.3`; `host1`: `3.1.1`

Edit 3: Here is the verbose (vvv) log of the rsync call, interestingly it is *identical* as the log of the working host...

```
+ /usr/bin/rsync -avvvz --include '*.tar.gz' --exclude '*' /backup/ user@host2:/backup
opening connection using: ssh -l user host2 rsync --server -vvvlogDtprze.iLsfxC . /backup  (9 args)
sending incremental file list
[sender] make_file(.,*,0)
[sender] pushing local filters for /backup/
[sender] showing file backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz because of pattern *.tar.gz
[sender] make_file(backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz,*,2)
send_file_list done
send_files starting
server_recv(2) starting pid=26231
recv_file_name(.)
recv_file_name(backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz)
received 16 names
recv_file_list done
get_local_name count=16 /backup
generator starting pid=26231
delta-transmission enabled
recv_generator(.,0)
set modtime of . to (1587261606) Sun Apr 19 04:00:06 2020
recv_generator(.,1)
recv_generator(backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz,16)
recv_files(16) starting
generate_files phase=1
send_files(0, /backup/.)
./
send_files(16, /backup/backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz)
send_files mapped /backup/backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz of size 91256
calling match_sums /backup/backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz
backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz
sending file_sum
false_alarms=0 hash_hits=0 matches=0
sender finished /backup/backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz
recv_files(.)
recv_files(backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz)
got file_sum
set modtime of .backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz.N8E3hW to (1587261606) Sun Apr 19 04:00:06 2020
renaming .backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz.N8E3hW to backup-20200419-0400.tar.gz
set modtime of . to (1587261606) Sun Apr 19 04:00:06 2020
send_files phase=1
recv_files phase=1
generate_files phase=2
send_files phase=2
send files finished
total: matches=0  hash_hits=0  false_alarms=0 data=91256
recv_files phase=2
recv_files finished
generate_files phase=3
generate_files finished

sent 91,346 bytes  received 3,723 bytes  190,138.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1,318,611  speedup is 13.87
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=0, file=main.c, line=1207): about to call exit(0)
```

Comment: try to use the rsync with -avvvz in this way you can see why is failing

Comment: Thanks, I attached the verbose log. Interestingly it is identical (modulo host name and such) to the log for the host that works correctly...

Comment: How certain are you that this directory is created by rsync? What is its mtime? Can you change the time of the cron job and check whether the directory mtime changes, too? Independend of that: Why use `rsync` at all for a single file and not `scp` or `sftp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a cronjob running on another host that was responsible for the empty folder. Silly mistake.